# c++ function cannot derive template for child class of base class with templates

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I am somewhat new to templates and I don't understand how the compiler derives the templates for child classes when I inherit from the base class in a way where I set the templates.

I am creating a genetic algorithm base class for which I have written an abstract base class for the individuals of a population. I want to have a general definition so I use templates to define the fenotype and genotype:

```
template<typename T, typename S>
class individual {
    public:
        individual(S& fenotyp, T& genotyp) :
            fenotype(fenotyp), genotype(genotyp) {}
        ...
        S fenotype;

        T genotype;
        ...
};
```

When the individuals are bitstrings, I have the following child class:

```
class bitstring_individual : public individual<boost::dynamic_bitset<>,
    boost::dynamic_bitset<>> {
    public:
        using individual::individual;
        ...
};
```

Now I no longer have to work with template brackets anymore. Further down the line, I have a function that given a population `std::vector<individual<T,S>>`, returns the half with the highest fitness. This works on any type of individual so we can keep the definition general:

```
template<typename T, typename S>
std::vector<individual<T,S>> select_best_half(std::vector<individual<T,S>> parents,
        std::vector<individual<T,S>> children) {
            ...
        }
```

However, if I call this function I get `error: no matching function for call to select_best_half(...)` and the compiler says `template argument deduction/substitution failed:` and `mismatched types ‘individual<T, S>’ and ‘bitstring_individual'`.

In the definition of `bitstring_individual` we see that:

```
bitstring_individual : individual<boost::dynamic_bitset<>,boost::dynamic_bitset<>>
```

so why does the compiler not understand that the templates should be `boost::dynamic_bitset<>`? Can someone help me understand how the compiler tackles this inheritance and how can I fix it?

Comment: [mcve] would be better and much cleaner instead of ton of words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(`using bitset = boost::dynamic_bitset`)

Your `bitstring_individual` is **not** the same as `individual<bitset, bitset>`, and the compiler rightfully does not recognize them as such. One inherits the other, yes, but that does not make them interchangeable everywhere - in particular when used as template arguments.

In short: vectors (and other containers) of different (even polymorphically related) types are not covariant. Just like you cannot pass a `std::vector<int>` to a function expecting a `std::vector<long>` you cannot pass a `std::vector<bitstring_individual>` where a `std::vector<individual<bitset, bitset>>` is expected.

*Note: Yes, they are different conversions, but the idea is the same.*

Imagine that `sizeof(individual<bitset, bitset>) = 32` and that `bitstring_individual` adds some members so that `sizeof(bitstring_individual) = 48`. If the compiler deduced `T = S = bitset`, then it would generate a method signature containing `std::vector<individual<bitset, bitset>>`, so a vector whose elements have size 32. But when you try to call it, you are passing a vector whose elements have size 48. Those vectors are not covariant, which would invariably lead to problems.

If you want your concrete individuals to have no other functionality than what the templated base class provides, just do this:

```
using bitstring_individual = individual<bitset, bitset>;
```

Otherwise, your vectors cannot store the individuals directly - you would have to use something like `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<individual<T, S>>>` (alternatively `unique_ptr` or `ref` instead of `shared_ptr`) for all population vectors.

Comment: This makes sense, thank you very much. I don't think I need additional functionality so I will trye your first suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Your question actually deals with [covariance and contravariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)) of (certain) types in C++. Even if you were to "hard-code" your template parameters, i.e. have:

```
using i_bs_bs = individual<bitset, bitset>;
using std::vector;

class bitstring_individual : public i_bs_bs { ... };

vector<bsi> select_best_half(vector<i_bs_bs> parents, vector<i_bs_bs> children) {
    ...
}
```

You'd still get an error passing a `vector<bitstring_individual>` to `select_best_half()`. Why? Because, **in C++ `std::vector<T>` is not a covariant type constructor**.

To take the the example from the linked-to Wikipedia page, Suppose your inheriting classes were `Animal` (base class) and `Cat` (derived class). In C++, you can't add an Animal to a vector of Cats. All elements of that vector need to be Cats. Similarly, and as @MaxLanghof's answer explains, you can't add a `bitstring_individual` to a vector whose elements are of `bitstring_individual`'s base type. Any special behavior necessary for handling `bitstring_individual` would simply not apply to the elements of a `vector<i_bs_bs>`.

Comment: I am going to read the Wikipedia page more thoroughly but if I understand you correctly, if `select_best_half` were to just take a `bitstring_individual` and return it it would work since I would circumvent `std::vector<T>`.

Comment: I am actually confused, why would your code not work? I understand that if I were to define `select_best_half` for `i_bs_bs`that it would not work. But in your code you define it specifically for `vector<bsi>` so I would expect it to work then.

Comment: `bsi` is not declared. If you intended it to alias `bitstring_individual`, then the code [compiles without issue](https://godbolt.org/g/N24L2d).

Comment: @MaxLanghof: Fixed.

Comment: @RichardSchoonhoven: Fixed.